# Is it ok to use Wilcoxon test in this case?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have to evaluate the efficiency of a treatment on 9 patients. I made pre and post-treatment acquisitions to obtain 11 different kinematic variables and each patient had to perform a certain movement 6 times, so I have 12 trials per patient.
Now, to make the statistical evaluation and determine if the treatment was effective, should I calculate the mean of the kinematic variables in order to have a single value in each case (pre and post) per patient?
To be more clear, something like this

```
       var1_pre    var1_post    ...    var11_pre   var11_post

n1    mean1_1pre                ...               mean11_1post

..                              ...

n9    mean1_9pre                ...               mean11_9post
```

At this point is it correct to apply the Wilcoxon test for 2 related samples and thus find if there is a significant difference in every variable between the pre and post condition?

Comment: For two dependent samples, you'll want to use the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test; https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-spss-statistics.php.

Comment: Thank you Jon, so is it correct to calculate the mean value of the variables among the 6 trials of the pre and the 6 of the post-treatment before using the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test?

Comment: Yes, if means are what you're interested in comparing

Comment: Wilcoxon deals with ranks.  The ranks are based on the sign of the difference between the paired sample values. The sample means have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelChernick yes, I know that. But since I'm using SPSS I have to compile a table with values, and it will perform the substitution with ranks automatically. My paired samples are the variables I've calculated in the pre and in the post-treatment. The fact is that for each of the 9 patients I acquired 6 trials in the pre and 6 in the post. So my doubt was if I can calculate the mean of the variables and then use the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test for each separate variable and see if there is a significant difference between pre and post.